# How to infer type parameters with inherited types?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, type-inference

I have the following setup:

```
public abstract class super { }

public class sub : super { }

public static void Foo<T>(T element, Action<T> action)
    where T : new()
{ }
```

And I want to do this:

```
Action<super> superAction = (s) => { };
Foo(new sub(), superAction);
```

However this fails, because the second line tries to call `Foo<super>` instead of `Foo<sub>`. This would work:

```
Foo<sub>(new sub(), superAction);
```

1. Is there anyway to infer the type parameter in a case like this?
2. Why does it not infer the correct type in the first place?

EDIT:
The problem comes down to the fact, that this is possible:

```
Action<sub> subAction = superAction;
```

But the compiler does not use this fact for it's inference logic.
So the answer to question 1 is:

```
Foo(new sub(), superAction as Action<sub>);
```

Question 2, why the compiler does not do this on its own, is still unsolved though.

EDIT2:
The short answer for question 2 is:
Based on the given parameters the compiler determines the possible generic types for this method call. If there are multiple options, it picks the 'highest' (or least derived) one. It does so for more or less arbitrary reasons.
Generic type constrains (the ones after `where` like `T : new()`) are not considered here.

Comment: Why do you have `where T : new()`?

Comment: @haim770 This is obviously just sample code. In my real problem Foo has to create another instance of T/sub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it not infer the correct type in the first place?

The compiler does infer the correct type. The correct type for the given method is `super`. Why? because that's how the type inference algorithm works.

Lets look at it.

Given the following method signature:

```
public static void Foo<T>(T element, Action<T> action) where T : new()
```

The algorithm starts at the first phase, which boils down for us to:

> - Otherwise, if Ei has a type U (Ei in our example is `T element`) and xi (xi is the method argument `Foo<T>` is a value parameter then a
>     **lower-bound inference is made from U to Ti.**

So the now we look at lower bound inference:

> - If V is one of the unfixed Xi then U is added to the set of exact
>     bounds for Xi.

This happens for the first type parameter, `T`, and for `Action<T>`, the following applies:

> - Otherwise, if V is C then inference depends on the i-th type
>     parameter of C:
> - If it is covariant then a lower-bound inference is
>     made.
> - If it is contravariant then an **upper-bound inference is made.**
> - If it is invariant then an exact inference is made.

Now, the second phase begins:

> - All unfixed type variables Xi which do not depend on (§7.5.2.5) any Xj
>     are fixed (§7.5.2.10).

Now lets see what fixing means:

> An unfixed type variable Xi with a set of bounds is fixed as follows:
>
> - The set of candidate types Uj starts out as the set of all
>     types in the set of bounds for Xi.
> - We then examine each bound for Xi in turn: For each exact
>     bound U of Xi all types Uj which are not identical to U are removed
>     from the candidate set. For each lower bound U of Xi all types Uj to
>     which there is not an implicit conversion from U are removed from the
>     candidate set. For each upper bound U of Xi all types Uj from which
>     there is not an implicit conversion to U are removed from the
>     candidate set.
> - If among the remaining candidate types Uj there is a **unique
>     type V from which there is an implicit conversion to all the other
>     candidate types, then Xi is fixed to V.**
> - Otherwise, type inference fails.

What happeneds here is that we basically have both `super` and `sub` in the valid candidate set for type `T`. Now, when the set of bounds both produce a "best match", **the type inference algorithm chooses the "larger" type.** [Eric Lippert talks about this in a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/10/02/how-do-we-ensure-that-method-type-inference-terminates.aspx):

> A "bound" is nothing more than a type, and a bound can be "upper",
>   "lower" or "exact". For example, suppose we have a type parameter T
>   with three bounds: a lower bound of Giraffe, an exact bound of Mammal,
>   and an upper bound of Animal. Let's say that Animal is a "larger" type
>   than Mammal (because all Mammals are Animals but not all Animals are
>   Mammals, thus Animal must be the larger type), and Giraffe is a
>   "smaller" type than Mammal. Given this set of bounds we know that T
>   must be inferred to be first, either Giraffe or a type larger than
>   Giraffe, because Giraffe is a lower bound; you can't infer a type
>   smaller than Giraffe. Second, we know that T must be Mammal, exactly.
>   And third, we know that T must be either Animal or a type smaller than
>   Animal, because Animal is an upper bound. We cannot infer a type
>   larger than Animal. The C# compiler deduces that Mammal is the only
>   type in the set that meets all three requirements, and so T would be
>   fixed to Mammal. **If there are multiple types in the set that meet all
>   the requirements (which of course cannot happen if there are any exact
>   bounds!) then we pick the largest such type.** (*)

Eric also explains why the "larger" type was picked:

> There is an argument to be made for picking the smallest, but picking
>   the largest seems to match more people's intuitions of what the right
>   choice is.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, I'm not sure covariance and contravariance has something to do with generic type inference. It won't compile for `Func<super>` as well (that *is* covariant).

Comment: So it basically comes down to: Because this feature is not implemented (yet)?

Comment: @TimPohlmann Yes, that's what I meant. It is not that the "feature isn't implemented", it's the fact that the type inference algorithm sees that there is a unique type, which is `super`, where an implicit conversion exists to all other candidate types.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Ah I see what you mean. However there exist implicit conversions to sub for all parameters as well. So that part is "not implemented". As PetSerAl  mentioned in his answer, the reason might be backwards compatibility.

Comment: @TimPohlmann See my edit, this has nothing to do with backwards compatibility. This has everything to do with the fact that type inference will choose the *larger type* of a set of candidates when there is more than one best match.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If the compiler would take implicit conversions of delegates into account, `sub` would be an upper bound. The point is, that it doesn't. And the reason given by PetSerAl seems totally valid to me.

Comment: @TimPohlmann The compiler doesn't take the delegate as a bound at all. The type inference algorithm is only in regarding to the type `T` of the `Action`. And `subs` can't be an upper bound to `super`, it's the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92720/discussion-between-tim-pohlmann-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: After all the discussions, things are getting clearer and this definitely seems to be the most precise answer

Comment: Conclusion: Yuval Itzchakov was right (I added a short summary in my question).

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to whether the compiler can (or cannot) infer the actual type of `T`.

When you're passing:

```
Foo(new sub(), superAction as Action<sub>);
```

The compiler can clearly determine that `T` can be resolved as `sub`, because it can be inferred from both arguments.

But, when you're simply passing:

```
Foo(new sub(), superAction);
```

The compiler is forced to determine that `T` must be `super` (the common type of the two, otherwise `Action<super>` cannot be accepted as an argument) and then you're back to the initial problem which is the `new` constraint. Because once `T` resolved as `super`, it doesn't comply with the `new` constraint (because it's `abstract` and the compiler cannot guarantee that it can be `new`ed).

Now, when you're doing:

```
Foo<sub>(new sub(), superAction);
```

It compiles fine and *that's* when variance comes into play. Because `Action<T>` is contravariant, the compiler *can* settle with `T` resolved as `sub` because `Action<super>` can be treated as `Action<sub>`.

Comment: After some research I actually came to the conclusion, that it probably does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd799517(v=vs.100).aspx The trick is, that the compiler is able to treat `superAction` as `Action<sub>` implicitly, if told doing so (in my example by `Foo`s type parameter). That only seems to be possible since .net 4 and is not fully supported for generic type parameters yet.

Comment: Excellent answer. This must be the real reason behind it... When i removed `new()` constraint it worked like a charm

Comment: It does relates to contravariance. I'm updating the answer

Comment: 'otherwise `Action<super>` can never be accepted as an argument' It should though, since `Action<super>` can be casted implicitly to `Action<sub>`. But it seems .net does not support that yet for whatever reason.

Comment: @TimPohlmann, That would probably be one step too far for the compiler. Perhaps the language designers can add more

Comment: @haim770 As PetSerAl pointed out in his answer it seems to be for backwards compatibility reasons.

Comment: @TimPohlmann Generic method type inference is about inferring the type parameters. The compiler doesn't take into account implicit conversions from `Action<super>` to `Action<sub>`, but from `super` to `sub` only.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I get that. The question is: Why not? And I think PetSerAl's reason is perfectly valid.

Comment: @TimPohlmann This is the reason, as Eric says it: *There is an argument to be made for picking the smallest, but picking the largest seems to match more people's intuitions of what the right choice is.* This, again, has nothing to do with implicit delegate conversions.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov see the comment below your question.

Comment: NVM Yuval Itzchakov's answer is correct. I added a short summary in my question.